# Is this XML format correct?

Tags: xml

I have never used XML before. I am trying to send a single XML file to SQL Server, where it will (hopefully) be able to be deconstructed and inserted into various tables.

I'm building tests. So for each test there are X questions, and for each question there are X answer options and 1 explanation of the correct answer. Is the following XML example valid? Am I missing anything that will simplify it?

```
<test>
    <testid>1</testid>
    <qablock>
        <question>
            <question_number>1</question_number>
            <question_text>What is 1 + 1?</question_text>
        </question>
        <explanation>It's 2.</explanation>
        <options>
            <option>
                <option_number>1</option_number>
                <option_value>1</option_value>
                <is_correct>0</is_correct>
            </option>
            <option>
                <option_number>2</option_number>
                <option_value>2</option_value>
                <is_correct>1</is_correct>
            </option>
            <option>
                <option_number>3</option_number>
                <option_value>3</option_value>
                <is_correct>0</is_correct>
            </option>
            <option>
                <option_number>4</option_number>
                <option_value>4</option_value>
                <is_correct>0</is_correct>
            </option>
            <option>
                <option_number>5</option_number>
                <option_value>5</option_value>
                <is_correct>0</is_correct>
            </option>
        </options>
    </qablock>
    <qablock>
        <question>
            <question_number>2</question_number>
            <question_text>What is 2 + 2?</question_text>
        </question>
        <explanation>It's 4.</explanation>
        <options>
            <option>
                <option_number>1</option_number>
                <option_value>1</option_value>
                <is_correct>0</is_correct>
            </option>
            <option>
                <option_number>2</option_number>
                <option_value>2</option_value>
                <is_correct>0</is_correct>
            </option>
            <option>
                <option_number>3</option_number>
                <option_value>3</option_value>
                <is_correct>0</is_correct>
            </option>
            <option>
                <option_number>4</option_number>
                <option_value>4</option_value>
                <is_correct>1</is_correct>
            </option>
            <option>
                <option_number>5</option_number>
                <option_value>5</option_value>
                <is_correct>0</is_correct>
            </option>
        </options>
    </qablock>
</test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got there is perfectly valid XML.  It doesn't have a schema associated (i.e. so you can validate the structure / ensure that an XML file you're given is as expected before using it so you don't get unexpected results.

You can add an XML header - that would help as it would tell the parser what character set to use - also check that you save the XML file with the encoding you specify in the header (let me know if you need more explanation on this point).

Finally though what you've got is fine, personally I'd write that XML slightly differently to make it smaller and easier to read.  There are no hard rules there, but generally speaking keeping file size down is good and being readable is good.

Finally I'd probably wrap this in a tests element; that way if you want to upload more than one test at a time it's easy to do (but you can still use this for one file at a time should you wish) - again no hard rule, but building in flexibility is always good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tests>
    <test testid='1'>
        <qablock number='1'>
            <question>What is 1 + 1?</question>
            <explanation>It's 2.</explanation>
            <options>
                <option number='1' value='1' />
                <option number='2' value='2' correct='true' />
                <option number='3' value='3' />
                <option number='4' value='4' />
                <option number='5' value='5' />
            </options>
        </qablock>
        <qablock number='2'>
            <question>What is 2 + 2?</question>
            <explanation>It's 4.</explanation>
            <options>
                <option number='1' value='1' />
                <option number='2' value='2'/>
                <option number='3' value='3' />
                <option number='4' value='4' correct='true'  />
                <option number='5' value='5' />
            </options>
        </qablock>
    </test>
</tests>
```

Hope that helps.

-----------edit----------------

Here's an example of this with SQL's xml data type;

```
declare @x xml

set @x = '<tests>
    <test testid=''1''>
        <qablock number=''1''>
            <question>What is 1 + 1?</question>
            <explanation>It''s 2.</explanation>
            <options>
                <option number=''1'' value=''1'' />
                <option number=''2'' value=''2'' correct=''true'' />
                <option number=''3'' value=''3'' />
                <option number=''4'' value=''4'' />
                <option number=''5'' value=''5'' />
            </options>
        </qablock>
        <qablock number=''2''>
            <question>What is 2 + 2?</question>
            <explanation>It''s 4.</explanation>
            <options>
                <option number=''1'' value=''1'' />
                <option number=''2'' value=''2''/>
                <option number=''3'' value=''3'' />
                <option number=''4'' value=''4'' correct=''true''  />
                <option number=''5'' value=''5'' />
            </options>
        </qablock>
    </test>
</tests>'

select @x.value('(/tests/test/qablock[@number=''2'']/question/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') Question
, @x.value('(/tests/test/qablock[@number=''2'']/options/option[@correct=''true'']/@number)[1]','nvarchar(max)') Answer
```

Comment: ps. I considered moving the correct flag to the options element rather than against the correct option and having it hold the correct option id - that way you could enforce one correct answer for each question - but if there's any potential for there to be more than one right answer it's better as it is above as this again gives that flexibility.

Comment: Wow, thanks! So, we won't be uploading or using an actual XML "file" per se. I'll just be building a big XML string which will be passed as a varchar(max) variable to sql server. So, in that context, is the header still applicable?

Comment: Probably no required if there's no file.  FYI: SQL has an XML datatype which you may be interested in - this allows you to play with XML within your SQL queries.  Here's the MSDN on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887(v=sql.105).aspx.  Give me a shout if you need anymore info/help here though.

Comment: Yep, that is what I will be working on all day today. Fingers crossed. And thanks again. You are a God among men. :)

Comment: How can I post a large-ish follow-up question with some SQL code?

Comment: I'd post as a new question, then stick a link to it in the comments here / put a link back to here in the question.

Comment: [link to follow-up thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983250/parsing-processing-xml-and-inserting-into-sql-tables)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to valid a XML

**Well Formed**

This is basically about the syntax (Your XML is well formed, I validated it).

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)

A well formed XML respects those rules

1. It contains only properly encoded legal Unicode characters.
2. None of the special syntax characters such as "<" and "&" appear
   except when performing their markup-delineation roles.
3. The begin, end, and empty-element tags that delimit the elements are
       correctly nested, with none missing and none overlapping.
4. The element tags are case-sensitive; the beginning and end tags must
   match exactly. Tag names cannot contain any of the characters
   !"#$%&'()*+,/;<=>?@[]^`{|}~, nor a space character, and cannot
   start with -, ., or a numeric digit.
5. There is a single "root" element that contains all the other
   elements.

You can valid your XML online [here](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)

**Valid XML**

A valid XML is about the content like in your XML, it would be something like a question should have at least 1 explanation.

For this you would need a [DTD](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/default.asp) or a [schema](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp) then validate it online